# How to render custom jsx element in Autocomplete material UI

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I need to add a Autocomplete dropdown in my UI that renders the jsx element when selected an option. I found *renderTags* props in the doc, but seems to be of no help. How can we acheive this . Thanks in advance.

https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/

Comment: Do you want to customize the options?

Comment: yes i wanted it too, but that is done by using renderOption props. I want to render the selected value . I need some icons in the selected box. @Kalhan.Toress